# Unity gameobject controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have seen WiFi, Bluetooth mobile phone based controllers to control game object. Is it possible to control using light LED or IR that can be taken as a controller?
I want to map a moving torch light with a cube...any possibility?

Comment: The answer is "yes, but..." and the "but..." part is: "you will need to find or create a plugin to communicate between the device and Unity."

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything as a controller with the right library and an Arduino.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPfGgjhW13I

Here is a video of how people could use bananas as controller (simulating keybowrd keys with an Arduino)